# Python to combine Excel spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel

Hello all…a question in using Panda to combine Excel spreadsheets.

The problem is that, sequence of columns are lost when they are combined. If there are more files to combine, the format will be even worse.

If gives an error message, if the number of files are big.

```
ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256)
```

What I am using is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in ['c:\\1635.xls', 'c:\\1644.xls']:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)] * len(data)
    df = df.append(data)

df.to_excel('c:\\CB.xls')
```

The original files and combined look like:
[image]

what's the best way to combine great amount of such similar Excel files?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `xlrd` and `xlwt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import xlwt
import xlrd
import os


current_file = xlwt.Workbook()
write_table = current_file.add_sheet('sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

key_list = [u'City', u'Country', u'Received Date', u'Shipping Date', u'Weight', u'1635']
for title_index, text in enumerate(key_list):
    write_table.write(0, title_index, text)


file_list = ['1635.xlsx', '1644.xlsx']

i = 1
for name in file_list:
    data = xlrd.open_workbook(name)

    table = data.sheets()[0]
    nrows = table.nrows
    for row in range(nrows):
        if row == 0:
            continue
        for index, context in enumerate(table.row_values(row)):
            write_table.write(i, index, context)
        i += 1


current_file.save(os.getcwd() + '/result.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `data.index = [os.path.basename(f)] * len(data)` you should use `df.reset_index()`.

For example:

1.xlsx:

```
a   b
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

2.xlsx:

```
a   b
4   4
5   5
6   6
```

code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame()

 for f in [r"C:\Users\Adi\Desktop\1.xlsx", r"C:\Users\Adi\Desktop\2.xlsx"]:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)

 df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
 df.to_excel('c:\\CB.xls')
```

cb.xls:

```
        a   b
    0   1   1
    1   2   2
    2   3   3
    3   4   4
    4   5   5
    5   6   6
```

If you don't want the dataframe's index to be in the output file, you can use `df.to_excel('c:\\CB.xls', index=False)`.

Comment: thanks so much for the help. amazing! it's very difficult to choose yours or the earlier as the best answer. hope you don't mind..